# I need some help with the format of a paper on overleaf.com

Tags: math-mode

I have been using a template for homework assignments in overleaf.com. It is working well, but unfortunately, there are some ugly checkboxes in every problem line. How do I make this go away ?

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb, graphicx, multicol, array}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}       {\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\title{Pigeonhole Principle}
\author{Name}
\maketitle

\begin{problem}{1}
Let $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$ be a sequence of integers. Prove that there is    always a subsequence $a_i, a_{i+1}, a_{i+2}, \dots a_{i+k}$, such that  $a_i +   a_{i+1} + \dots a_{i+k}$ is a multiple of $n$.
\end{problem}

\begin{proof}
Write a solution here
\end{proof}

\begin{problem}{2}
If there are $25$ points, such that among any three of them there are two     who's distance is less than $1$. Prove that there is always a circle of radius    $1$ which contains $13$ points.
\end{problem}

\begin{proof}
Write a solution here
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The problem is at the end of the solution line there is a box, which I want to remove.

Comment: Do you really expect people to be able to tell you which lines should be added or removed in an unknown document using an unknown template to correct an unknown output?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm new to LaTeX and this site. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Show us the code. Mind you, we likely don't need to see *all* the problems. Make a copy of your file, and remove code as much as you can from it, without removing the problem. (That is a very short description of how you make  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).) Then copy that entire code and paste it into your question.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you learn how to ask questions. Spent a few hours to read questions here that got an answer and try to figure out which information was needed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have posted it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I expect that the box comes from the use of the `\begin{proof}` environment. The box is not a tick box, it's a mathematical symbol which signifies the end of a proof. Try using a different environment, such as `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{align}` and let us know if that helps.

Comment: @samcarter's comment provides the solution.  Go to that referenced question and implement the first answer's solution.   p.s. I would not use the proof environment for the solution of a homework problem.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Its not a homework problem. I like collecting problems with elegant solutions and proofs. So, I'm kind of just writing a paper for myself to collect beautiful problems and proofs. It was the default environment given by the template I choose. I don't know much about what the alternatives are.

Comment: @NatalieHogg Actually, now that I know it's a mathematical symbol I don't really feel like changing it. Thanks for the info. What is the symbol called ?

Comment: The tombstone, Halmos, end of proof, or Q.E.D. mark is used in mathematics to denote the end of a proof, in place of the traditional abbreviation "Q.E.D."